# This reduction maps to which group? General linear group reduced to spin group then squared.

Tags: group-theory, clifford-algebras

Suppose a multivector $\mathbf{u}$ of $G(\mathbb{R}^{3,1})$ (a multivector of geometric algebra 3+1 dimensions.

$$
\mathbf{u} = \exp (a + \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{f} + \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{b})
$$

where $a$ is a scalar, $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector, $\mathbf{f}$ is a bivector, $\mathbf{v}$ is a pseudovector and $\mathbf{b}$ is a pseudoscalar.

Clearly, $\mathbf{u}$ is a realization of ${\rm GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$.

---

My first question,

If I pose $\mathbf{x}\to 0, \mathbf{v} \to 0$, what group does it map to?

$$
\mathbf{u}|_{\mathbf{x}\to 0, \mathbf{v}\to 0}=\exp (a+\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{b})
$$

---

My second question,

If I now square the result, what group does it map to?

$$
\mathbf{u} \to \mathbf{u}^2
$$

becomes

$$
(\mathbf{u}|_{\mathbf{x}\to 0, \mathbf{v}\to 0})^2=\exp 2(a+\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{b})
$$

Comment: Since scalars and pseudoscalars commute with bivectors ($a\mathbf f=\mathbf fa$ and $a\mathbf b=\mathbf ba$ and $\mathbf f\mathbf b=\mathbf b\mathbf f$), we have $$\exp(a+\mathbf f+\mathbf b)=\exp(a)\exp(\mathbf f)\exp(\mathbf b).$$ It's a direct product of smaller groups.

Comment: @mr_e_man Interesting... so $\mathbb{R}\times SO(3,1) \times U(1)$? The square is the same, right?

Comment: @mr_e_man actually, since $\exp(\mathbf{f})$ is a double cover of SO(3,1), then $\mathbb{R} \times spin(3,1) \times U(1)$?

Comment: The exponential of a real number is positive, so the first part would be $\mathbb R_{>0}$. For the second part, keep in mind that $SO(3,1)$ contains things like $-I$ (with determinant $(-1)^4=+1$), which are disconnected from the identity matrix $I$ because they reverse the time direction. So that should be $SO^+(3,1)$, or $Spin^+(3,1)$, which is connected. Also note that the first and third parts can be combined: $\mathbb R_{>0}\times U(1)\cong(\mathbb C\setminus\{0\})$.